# Search Results Count Missing

Tags: bug, design

There appears to be a bug on the SO search results page. Admittedly, I don't use search that often so I may be mistaken but it appears that the number of results returned is not displayed in the right hand sidebar.

[image]

If a number is never shown there and this is normal behavior, is the "gap" of white space desirable and the expected behavior?

Comment: _(To be read in the annoying tour guide voice)_ And if you'll look to your left, under the search bar, you'll see a count of results returned! (Note: This is not meant to be rude- If you take it as such, my apologies for terrible humor.) No, the number of results returned is never shown there for searches. As for the whitespace, I don't know one way or another.

Comment: @Kendra No offense taken at all. I did see the number to the left. Like I said, I don't use it much (I prefer to google stackoverflow: {query} as I usually find more relevant results this way). Anyway, it seemed like a spot where it could be appropriate or may have been appropriate. The white space just feels a bit large compared to that below it separating it from the cat ad. I'm more for consistency on things like that but to each their own. It gets the job done either way.

Comment: Yeah, I can agree the whitespace seems large (now that it's pointed out) but I don't know if it's intentional or not. And I assumed you just used google, to be honest- It tends to work better. :)

Comment: @Kendra Indeed it does. Thanks for the comments. I appreciate the feedback.